# How Do I Prevent Screen Recording

Tags: c#, winforms

i am working in a windows forms App(C#), which contain Windows media player to play encrypted video ,i.e due to security purpose the application should decrypt the video file and then play it using the media player

the problem now,
if any one play the video and then run any screen recording application so he can easily get the video

so, 
the question is:
how to prevent screen recording while my application is running?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the job of the Windows Media Player component? I mean, that level of security should be enforced at the system level, not the app level, or else anyone could make a player that also captures the screen to rip protected content. Have you observed this in action or are you just speculating?

Comment: You can't. Even if you could, the user could just take a physical video of their screen. If the video is being played on the computer, it can be accessed.

Comment: I'm not so sure, @Doorknob. On slower computers I have dragged a playing video window around the screen only to see the video content lagging behind a large black rectangle in the window I was dragging. It told me that the video content was following a different path to the screen than the other UI components in the window.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: you can't.  Even if, somehow, you forced Windows to not allow any application to record the screen, a truly dedicated user could simply point a recording device at their screen (and a really dedicated user would figure out some other way around it).  If you show this to your users, you'll just have to trust that they're going to play fair with it.

The other part of this is: you probably don't have to worry about it.  For a screen recorder to do a reasonable job of capturing video requires a lot of processing and memory resources.  The average computer will have a hard time keeping up with both decrypting, decoding, playing, and recording video all at once - and the average user will get too frustrated even if they think to try.

You could try to make it a little bit harder by looking for popular screen recording products and refusing to play the video if that process is running (or installed?).  That won't be foolproof, but it would be another deterrent, e.g.

```
Process [] skypes = Process.GetProcessesByName("skype.exe");
Process[] otherRecorders = Process.GetProcessesByName("recorder.exe");

if (skypes.Length > 0 || otherRecorders.Length > 0) // don't play
```

Of course, this is still complicated by the possibility of those processes running under different credentials that your app can't access (require your app to run as admin?), and some processes will have weird names (the Skype Windows Store app for example).

Comment: Good points, Dan, but don't forget that Skype, GoToMeeting, and other teleconferencing apps have a "share my screen" option that works with playing video. Yes, frames are sometimes dropped, but it's not that hard, I suppose.

Comment: Right, so Skype, GoToMeeting, etc. might be processes you look for before allowing the video to play.  But again, it's probably not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible that you can break the DLL the makes the screen recording when the application is working